# PyAudio M1 Mac issue

Tags: python, apple-m1, pyaudio, macos-big-sur, portaudio

I have been suffering to install PyAudio in my M1 Macbook Pro lately. But I finally able to install it. First I installed portaudio using this command: `brew install portaudio`.

Then I successfully installed PyAudio using this command:

```
   pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='- 
   I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='- 
   L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio
```

I also checked the directory so that there's no mistake. But whenever I test PyAudio by importing it, it gives me this error:

`Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/arannya/Documents/Python Projects/VASS/main.py", line 1, in <module> import pyaudio File "/Users/arannya/Documents/Python Projects/VASS/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module> import _portaudio as pa ImportError: dlopen(/Users/arannya/Documents/Python Projects/VASS/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap Referenced from: /Users/arannya/Documents/Python Projects/VASS/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/arannya/Documents/Python Projects/VASS/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_portaudio.cpython-39-darwin.so`

Please help me. Thanks in advance.